# Transition does not work in Opera

Tags: css, opera, css-transitions

Do you guys have an idea why the following CSS3 transition does not work in Opera, even though -o-transition was used? Firefox and IE 10 render the menu item correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/JYLZ3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following syntax instead:

```
-o-transition-property: background-color;
-o-transition-duration: 4s;
```

I just modified the fiddle and this indeed works in Opera 11.62. In fact, it appears you could just use the shorthand form, but include `-color` to make it work with Opera:

```
-o-transition: background-color 5s;
```

Source: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-transitions-and-2d-transforms/

Comment: Actually, it doesn't like "background". "background-color" seems to work.

Comment: @smares Same conclusion I came to in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Opera 12 alpha. `-o-transition: background 5s` will work.